# Why does Android WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl() fail to render the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, webkit

Given this page:
http://music.10086.cn/newweb/qk/guoso/1C5DB9AC5C346441/t/6.html

A WebView with JavaScript turned on can open it properly with loadUrl() and render the JavaScript.

However, if the content of the page is loaded separately using a HTTP client, and given to loadDataWithBaseUrl() with the base URL set, the JavaScript does not work properly:

```
// store http://music.10086.cn/newweb/qk/guoso/1C5DB9AC5C346441/t/6.html into data

webView.loadUrl("http://music.10086.cn/", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I suspect that the remote scripts are not loading. How can I make the WebView log this?

This is on Android Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3.

Comment: I have seen the same thing with local JS and CSS. Maybe some security enforcement that they introduced in ICS?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Yes, perhaps. But it will take up too much time to go through the Android WebKit source code to debug.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to double-check:

1. You have included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. You have called `webView.getWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
3. Your HTML is well-formed

The following code worked for me, loading jquery from http://code.jquery.com/:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    String mimeType = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";
    String html = "<html>  "
      + "<script src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>"
      + "<script language='javascript'>"
      + "function sayHello() {       "
      + "alert(typeof($));    "
      + "}  </script>  "
      + "<body>    "
      + "   <a onClick='sayHello()'><div style='width:80px; "
      + "   margin:0px auto;  " + "  padding:10px;    "
      + "text-align:center;   " + " border:2px solid #202020;' > "
      + "<br> "
      + "    Click me!   " + "</div></a> " + " </body>" + " </html>";
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://code.jquery.com/", html, mimeType, encoding,null);
}
```